# Android and MS Sql Conncetion

Tags: android, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I am getting an error to connect with MS Sql. Could you please help me find the error, this is my code:

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void  SqlConnectTest(View view)
    {
        Log.i("Android"," SQL Connect Example.");
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);   
        Connection conn = null;
            try {
            //String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
            //"net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
            //Class.forName(driver);
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Log.i("Android"," SQL Class Connect Example.");
```

I get this warning, then the execution is stopped.

```
04-02 10:33:40.002: W/Error connection(1646): net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: ... do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got a Result

First need to drag and drop the jtds-1.2.5.jar in libs folder

its avoid the connection error from JDBC

After Give a connection string like 
String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IPaddress:1433;databaseName=DB;user=XXXX;password=XXXX;";

After you need to open a SQL Server manager to enable all TCP Port and pass the port no as 1433

Atlast declare

in AndroidManifest.xml